# MKMapView doesn't zoom and animate on iPad REAL DEVICE with iOS6

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios-simulator, mkmapview

I have UITableView with coordinates (stored in arrays) showed on every row, and I want to center (zooming and animating) my MKMapView on these coordinates when I tap table rows. This is the simple classic didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    latitude = [dataSourceLatitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    longitude = [dataSourceLongitude objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center.latitude = latitudine.floatValue;
    region.center.longitude = longitude.floatValue;
    region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.20;
    region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.20;
    [map setRegion:region animated:TRUE];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Well, it works with every simulator and device, but not on iPad REAL DEVICE with iOS6: here I can see map zoom and center on the coordinates ONLY THE FIRST time I tap a table row; with following taps on another row I see the map centering directly on coordinates, without zooming and animating. So this is the situation:

```
iPhone 5.1 simulator = it works!
iPad 5.1 simulator = it works
iPhone 5.1 REAL DEVICE = it works!

iPhone 6 simulator = it works!
iPad 6 simulator = it works
iPad 6 REAL DEVICE = it DOESN'T WORK!
```

**EDIT:** I have problems also with the pinView animatesDrop: on iPad REAL DEVICE with iOS6 I can't see the dropping animation, but pins snaps directly on the map. I have used this elegant code from @Anna Karenina and it doesn't works ONLY on iOS6:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)annotationViews
{
    NSTimeInterval delayInterval = 0;       
    for (MKAnnotationView *annView in annotationViews)
    {
        CGRect endFrame = annView.frame;           
        annView.frame = CGRectOffset(endFrame, 0, -500);            
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.500
                              delay:delayInterval
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{ annView.frame = endFrame; }
                         completion:NULL];         
        delayInterval += 0.1500;
    }
}
```

Is it a well-known issue? Can I resolve it? Thanks!

Comment: have you solved it? what was the problem, please post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In all these cases are you using exactly the same coordinates? The animation is skipped if your current view is too far away from the target view. For example: Whole of Europe -> Italy = smooth zoom.  1st Street, Nobodyville, OH -> Le First Street, PetiteVille, France = instant snap.

Comment: Hey Craig! No, the animation is skipped also if I have two near coordinates (ex: two streets in the same city), and btw I can reproduce this issue ONLY on iOS6 iPad real device...